# How to get image data from OpenCV matrix without extra allocation?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to do the following:

1. Make a copy of Cv::mat i retrieved somehow
2. Transform it
3. Return pointer to data to caller along with meta information (size, format, etc)
4. When i am done, free the data

The code i am using is:

```
cv::Mat m(...); //here is source image

cv::Mat *img  = new cv::Mat(m.clone());// copy the data
//do transformations
(*result)->pdata = img->data; // pointer to data gois to out parameter
img->addref(); //to prevent freeing the image data after tempo
delete img; //dispose of temporary object

...

delete [] outparam->pdata; //result == &outparam; free data after use
```

However, when executed, this code produces an assertion failure on:

```
_ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));
```

How should i achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3):

You can create `Mat` object for pre-allocated memory. In such case reference counting will be disabled and object won't free this memory in destructor:

```
cv::Mat m(...);
Mat img(rows, cols, type, (*result)->pdata);
m.copyTo(img);
...
delete [] (*result)->pdata;
```

Comment: I transform the cv::mat object, changing its size and color; i am pretty sure that changes both size of allocated data and data themselves - that is why i want to get data after transformations

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is implemented by the reference counting of OpenCV. It is a much better idea to rely on it rather than using points and allocations yourself.

```
cv::Mat m(...);
cv::Mat img = m; // this does not copy data, all the changes in img will be in m as well
// ... use img
// no delete necessary
```

Note that if you want to transform the data without deleting the original content, you do need to copy the data. In such a case:

```
cv::Mat m(...)
cv::Mat img = m.clone(); // this copies data, m and img can be used as two different Mats
// ... use img
// no delete necessary, img will be automatically deallocated
```

If when the deallocation occurs is important, you can control it with the scope:

```
cv::Mat m(...)
{
  cv::Mat img = m.clone();
  ...
} // img is automatically deleted here
// img is no longer available
```

Comment: lst example is closest to what i want with one exception. I want image data from img to be avaiable after - and return them to client.Altenatively, underlting C structure will probably do. For now i am just using memcpy, but there should be a way without it.

Comment: When you do return img; you return your matrix and no data is copied, just the headers. It is much safer to use cv::Mat copies and clone function than dealing yourself with the memory allocations.

Comment: I neither do nor can return img, since it is an object - i have to return just the data